# Как взять id от firebasecloud Messaging(FCM)

Tags: objective-c, swift

Как взять id от Firebasecloud Messaging(FCM). Чтобы потом его отправить на WebServer. Благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cделайте импорт библиотек в `AppDelegate`.

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
```

Если вы все правильно подключили, то в `AppDelegate` вам надо прописать метод

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
     if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
     }
 }
```

в `print` у вас  будет выводиться токен юзера и его можете отправлять на сервер. Для всех юзеров он будет уникальным. Удачи.